# What is the best way to make Kopi Luwak coffee?

Tags: coffee

I received a bag as a gift and want to take the proper measures to brewing the best cup of coffee possible.

Comment: Haha, when I read the title, I understood, "what is the best way to make Kopi Luwak coffee beans", I was expecting a lot of fun answers :) DIY Kopi Luwak anyone?

Comment: It seems redundant to say Kopi Luwak Coffee as the word `kopi` is actually the translation of the word `coffee` in Indonesian.

Answer (score 4):

I found someone posted out some suggestions here. http://www.realkopiluwak.com/perfect-cup/

I had it once before as espresso and it's a very smooth coffee. I reckon it isn't too hard to make a good one, but I reckon using siphon may be a good idea. It's best to get its natural flavor out.

Answer (score 2):

My fourth pack of Luwak coffee arrived today, I have a mug full beside me.

Use whichever method you prefer. It's fine and works just the same as other coffee in a percolator or plunger.

However, if you can stay at the stove for about 15 minutes, the best taste by far, in my opinion, is made by brewing in a saucpan.

Use a generous teaspoon of ground coffee for each cup you want to make, plus one for the pot.

For one cup measure one and a half cups of cold water into the pot, and the coffee grounds to the cold water. Heat on medium high, stirring frequently.

WATCH THE SAUCEPAN. As soon as it comes to the boil, remove from the heat. Stir again and allow the coffee grounds to settle to the bottom, 1 - 2 minutes. Pour the coffee carefully into you cup leaving the grounds behind. Enjoy.

With this method you MUST pay attention, if you find the coffee boiling, it's probably spoilt and will taste burnt.

Comment: Could you pour the finished coffee into one of those cone/filter set-ups (unbleached filters, of course) to capture the used grounds, or would that compromise the flavor/composition of this type of coffee? I'm guessing the sediment might add to the flavor, and the filter would, of course, catch most of that.

Comment: You mean when it comes to a simmer, right?   Pretty widely agreed (see other SE questions) that, ideally, coffee shouldn't actually boil ...